# ORA-06550:PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call;ORA-06550:

Tags: vb.net, oracle, stored-procedures, arguments

Simple insert operation via vb.net but getting error:

**ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PROCEDURE_NAME'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:**

May be I am missing or overlooking something. Some help will be really appreciated.

SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure SG.PROCEDURE_NAME(
        TypeDefinitionFinal in Char,
        TypeValueFinal in Char,
        ValidFrom in Char,
        ValidTo in Char,
        MethodType in integer,
        MethodValue in number,
        Reason in Char,
        CurrentTimeStamp in Date,
        LoggedUser in Char,
        StoresList in Char
) as

begin

    INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
      (TYPE_DEFINITION, TYPE_VALUE, VALID_FROM, VALID_TO, METHOD, VALUE, REASON, CREATE_TIMESTAMP, ENTERED_BY) 
    VALUES
       (TypeDefinitionFinal ,TypeValueFinal ,ValidFrom ,ValidTo ,MethodType ,MethodValue ,Reason ,CurrentTimeStamp ,LoggedUser );

end;
/
```

VB.NET Code:

```
Dim OraCommand As New OracleCommand("SG.PROCEDURE_NAME", OraConnection)
OraCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

OraCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("TypeDefinitionFinal", OracleType.Char)).Value = TypeDefinitionFinal
OraCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("TypeValueFinal", OracleType.Char)).Value = TypeValueFinal
OraCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("ValidFrom", OracleType.Char)).Value = ValidFrom
OraCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("ValidTo", OracleType.Char)).Value = ValidTo
OraCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("MethodType", OracleType.Int32)).Value = MethodType
OraCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("MethodValue", OracleType.Number)).Value = MethodValue
OraCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("Reason", OracleType.Char)).Value = Reason
OraCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("CurrentTimeStamp", OracleType.DateTime)).Value = CurrentTimeStamp
OraCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("LoggedUser", OracleType.Char)).Value = LoggedUser
OraCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("StoreList", OracleType.Char)).Value = StoreList

OraCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: what is the value for CurrentTimeStamp  in VB.Net Code

Comment: Your last `Add` is referring to `StoreList` instead of `StoresList`, but not sure if it's using the names here, and if so if they all need to be upper-case (as they are not quoted identifiers in the procedure declaration)?

Comment: Alex Poole, it was the misspelled 'StoresList'. You pointed out the issue, and my problem is fixed. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: The same error? Or is it a permission error?  BTW, people don't know your talking to them if you don't reference their name properly. Use the "@" sign followed by their name. IE, @AlexPoole, you should put your comment as the answer so this can be marked as the answer.

Comment: @Steve - thanks for the ping; I might have checked back eventually but who knows. I've turned that into an answer but as it was so simple I've also voted to close as a typo...

Comment: Thanks @Steve - ll keep in mind. I was trying to post my last comment as answer, but couldn't find that option, so eventually selected the UP arrow to have it highlighted somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a parameter name discrepancy. In your procedure definition you have:

```
        StoresList in Char
```

But in your VB code you have a slightly different name, missing an `s`:

```
OraCommand.Parameters.Add(New OracleParameter("StoreList", OracleType.Char)).Value = StoreList
```

Change `"StoreList"` to `"StoresList"`, or change the procedure definition to `StoreList` - doesn't matter which way you do it as long as they match.